# Facing Problems while creating First Maven Project in Eclipse version 2020-06

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

While creating a Maven Project in Eclipse version 2020-06, I'm facing three problems:-

1. Not getting the Maven Project option under File->New, but it is present under Project Section. [No Maven Project Option Present in File->New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad8rn.png)
2. Not getting any *.java* file under src/main/java.
   [No .java file under src/main/java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBcOU.png)
3. Not getting any custom Archetype.
   [No custom Archetype present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V10E.png)

**NOTE:- I am using JDK 1.8 and JRE 1.8 in Windows 7.**

How to add all this for the Maven Project? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

1. It just works like this. What is wrong with it?
2. Just add your .java file. Right click -> new -> class/interface/whatever
3. I think you have to wait. In the bottom-right corner we can see "Retrieving archetypes". It can take a few minutes to download everything

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective' to customize the current perspective. Choose 'Shortcuts' and then 'Maven > Maven Project' to add that to 'File > New'.

It is up to you to create new Java files.